# Unable to get the output from a powershell command using python script

Tags: python, powershell

I have a powershell command with an OutFile. It is working perfectly fine when I am running directly from the powershell console. It is capturing the output in a text file.
But when I am trying to run the same command using a python script, it is not giving any error, but it is generating an empty text file. Can I get a solution to this problem.
I am using subprocess method.

the code is like this:

```py
import subprocess,;
process=subprocess.run(["powershell", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted", "<Powershell command> | Out-File C:\PythonScripts\out.txt"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True);
print(process.stdout)
```

Comment: You are piping the output in the command itself into a file `out.txt`, and also expect it to go to stdout? Not sure if that is supposed to work:)

Comment: @JonatanÖström is right, you either evaluate the content of the textfile in python or you use `Tee-Object` in PowerShell when you fill your textfile.

Comment: @Thomas, can you show the code for that? I think I have tried it before and that did not work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture `stdout`, you have to write something to `stdout`. Piping to `Tee-Object` will write to `stdout` and a file simultaneously:

```py
import subprocess
process=subprocess.run(["powershell", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", r"'Hello World!' | Tee-Object -FilePath C:\PythonScripts\out.txt"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
print(process.stdout)
```

Output:

```
b'Hello World!\r\n'
```

And a file containing "Hello World!".

If you don't need the file, just write to `stdout`:

```py
import subprocess
process=subprocess.run(["powershell", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", r"'Hello World!'"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
print(process.stdout)
```

Output:

```
b'Hello World!\r\n'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I missed the r before the powershell command hence was getting an empty file.